# Google Weather city list

Tags: google-weather-api

is there a possibility to get a list of all cities preferably by country?
I'd like to add some locations I already visited on my homepage but for some cities I get no result because they are obviously not supported by the Google Weather API. So I like to get at least the nearest location that is supported.

Comment: Ok, as there are no answers, I think that it is not possible to get such a list. As alternative it is possible to call the method with longitude and latitude. But even that doesn't always work, take for example the following: http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=,,,25337500,34741944 which is a spot near Abu Dabab in Egypt. So it is necessary to have a fallback.

Comment: **The Google weather API was shut down in 2012** -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145820/google-weather-api-gone/35943521

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find such a list anywhere. However, using the API adwords city list seems to work anytime there is meteo datas available...maybe should you try this:

http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/adwords/docs/appendix/cities_world.html
CSV : http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/adwords/docs/appendix/cities_world.csv

Comment: Good hint, but that didn't actually help. I have lots of places that work but are not in that list. Anyway thank you for bothering...